# How can I keep variable value if validation fails in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-2

I want to validate a form to make sure a user entered something in the description field in this situation form validation is correct.

But,

Here , I pass value to **function 2** by fetching values from **function 1**

When **function 2** loads first time it fetch data and display the values (OK)

But When function 2 resubmit for validation and submision data these valitable get empoty and it throw the error `Message: Undefined variable: query` (ERROR)

I don't know how to do this, hehe. I'm just a newbie PHP programmer.

Here's what I have so far:

**function 1**

```
public function ask()
{
$this->load->model('MainM');
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('index', 'AL Index', 'trim|required|min_length[7]|max_length[7]');
if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->load->view('enterindex');
    }else{
        $query = null; //emptying in case 
        $index = $this->input->post("index"); //getting from post value
        $query = $this->db->get_where('tbl_reg', array('reg_index' => $index));         
        $count = $query->num_rows(); //counting result from query           
        if ($count == 1) {
        $data['query'] = $this->MainM->getregdata($index);  
        $result = $this->load->view('submitques',$data);
    }else{
        $data = array();
        $data['error'] = 'error';
        $this->load->view('enterindex', $data);
    }   
}
```

**function 2**

```
public function submitq()
{
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('yourq', 'Question', 'required|min_length[7]'); 
    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {            
        $this->load->view('submitques',$data);
    } else {        
     //insert the submitq form data into database
        $data = array(
            'reg_id' => $this->input->post('reg_id'),
            'ques' => $this->input->post('yourq'),
            'call' => "yes",
            'status' => "New",
            'date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
        );
            if ($this->db->insert('tbl_ques', $data))                   
        {
            // success
           $this->session->set_flashdata('success_msg', 'Your Submission is success');
           redirect('main/submitq');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('submitques', $data);
        }     
    }   

}
```

Comment: `$_POST` data won't persist after a refresh, which explains why on reload you're losing it.

Given that, if you reload you have two choices: figure out a way to repost (via POST) the data or handle the fact that `submitq` is being reloaded and not run the `form_validation`. Having said that, what exactly are you trying to do? It looks like you're trying to split the work among two methods but it's not clear how you are trying to do it

Comment: @Javier Larroulet Thanks friend then I'll try something out. any suggestions ?

Comment: It would help to know exactly what you're trying to orchestrate. With the code you provided, I can guess there's a view passing data to `ask()` through a form, after which you display another view which then passes (presumably) data to `submitq` via another form. Is that so? You need to be specific (and show the views too)

Comment: @user3766509 actually I'm answering first, why are you accepting the copy-paste answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actully you have $data variable put in else part so thats why this error appeared you need to define before loop.

```
public function submitq()
{
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('yourq', 'Question', 'required|min_length[7]'); 
// define here before check condtions
    $data = array(
        'reg_id' => $this->input->post('reg_id'),
        'ques' => $this->input->post('yourq'),
        'call' => "yes",
        'status' => "New",
        'date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
    );
    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {            
        $this->load->view('submitques',$data);
    } else {        
        //insert the submitq form data into database
            if ($this->db->insert('tbl_ques', $data))                   
        {
            // success
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success_msg', 'Your Submission is success');
            redirect('main/submitq');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('submitques', $data);
        }     
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to use the posted `$data` variable on `false` condition, you could moving it up outside the validation block :

```
public function submitq()
{
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('yourq', 'Question', 'required|min_length[7]'); 
    $data = array(
        'reg_id' => $this->input->post('reg_id'),
        'ques' => $this->input->post('yourq'),
        'call' => "yes",
        'status' => "New",
        'date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
    );
    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {            
        $this->load->view('submitques',$data);
    } else {        
        //insert the submitq form data into database
            if ($this->db->insert('tbl_ques', $data))                   
        {
            // success
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success_msg', 'Your Submission is success');
            redirect('main/submitq');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('submitques', $data);
        }     
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with This Code:

First Add Form Library to config/autoload.php

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','form_validation');
```

**html Code**

This is view file **login.php**

```
  <?php echo form_open('action_controller_name', array('class' => '', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data', 'role' => 'form', 'name' => 'myform', 'id' => 'myform')); ?>
  <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="mobile">Mobile-No</label>
      <input type="text" name="mobile" value="" placeholder="Enter Mobile No" id="mobile" class="form-control" /> 
      <label class="error"><?php echo form_error('mobile'); ?></label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="password">Password</label>
      <input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password" id="password" class="form-control" /> 
      <label class="error"><?php echo form_error('mobile'); ?></label>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-gray" id="submit" /> 
  <a class="forgotten" href="<?php echo base_url('login/forgot_password'); ?>" style="font-size: 13px;">Forgot Password</a> 
  <?php
  echo form_close();
  ?>
```

**My Action Controller**

```
public function action_controller_name() {
        $this->load->helper(array('form'));  // Load Form Library
        $this->load->library('form_validation'); // Load Form Validaton Library
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('mobile', 'mobile', 'required', array('required' => 'Please Enter Mobile Number.'));
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required', array('required' => 'Please Enter passsword.'));
        if ($this->form_validation->run() === TRUE) {  // Check validation Run
            // Your Login code write here
        } else {
            $this->load->view('login', $this->data);
        }
    }
```

Try this code.You can keep variable value if validation fails in codeigniter successfully.